# Is this a PHP associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

I was following [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/creating-an-api-centric-web-application%5d%5b1%5d/) on tutplus, and I came across this code snippet:

```
//check if the action exists in the controller. if not, throw an exception.
   if( method_exists($controller, $action) === false ) {
      throw new Exception('Action is invalid.');
   }

   //execute the action
   $result['data'] = $controller->$action();
   $result['success'] = true;

} catch( Exception $e ) {
   //catch any exceptions and report the problem
   $result = array();
   $result['success'] = false;
   $result['errormsg'] = $e->getMessage();
}

//echo the result of the API call
echo json_encode($result);
exit();
```

I am a beginner in PHP and I was wondering if `result` is an associative array? Can someone kindly confirm this? How can one tell the difference between an associative array and a non-associative array?

Comment: Yes. Because you are providing each element in the array with a key name.

Comment: It is an associative array. It associates keys: "sucess", "errormsg" with values.

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on the documentation. http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: traditional indexed arrays use a zero base with values instead of Key Value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result` is an associative array, because you assign a key-name.

A "normal" array doesn't have a key-name.

Answer (score 4):

To check associative array or not, you can use this function

```
    function is_assoc($var)
    {
            return is_array($var) && array_diff_key($var,array_keys(array_keys($var)));
    }

    function test($var)
    {
            echo is_assoc($var) ? "I'm an assoc array.\n" : "I'm not an assoc array.\n";
    }

    // an assoc array
    $a = array("a"=>"aaa","b"=>1,"c"=>true);
    test($a);
```

Comment: This is a _great_ way to get a beginner off to more self-study, as they start wondering what those functions do.

Comment: Yes. Good that you came in from a different angle.

Answer (score 0):

alternative.

```
function is_assoc(array $arr):bool{
    $keys= array_keys($arr);
    return count(array_flip(array_map(function ($item) {
            return (int)(is_string($item) && !preg_match('/^-?\d+$/', $item)   );
        },$keys))) === 1 && is_string($keys[0]) && !preg_match('/^-?\d+$/', $keys[0]);
}
```

test

```
$arr=['a'=>1,'b'=>2];
$arr2=['a'=>1,'1'=>2];
$arr3=['1'=>1,'a'=>2];
$arr4=['1'=>1,'2'=>2];
var_dump(is_assoc($arr));
var_dump(is_assoc($arr2));
var_dump(is_assoc($arr3));
var_dump(is_assoc($arr4));
```